# Does android-wear watch keep the accelerometer always on to turn on the screen automatically?

Tags: android, accelerometer, battery, wear-os

I m wondering how android watch automatically turn on the screen when you face it towards you, or how it counts the number of steps? if it keeps the accelerometer always on, doesn't it drain the battery?

If I listen to accelerometer values 24x7, will it drain any additional battery?

Comment: This is not a programming question and should not be asked here.

Comment: My app need to get values from accelerometer for all day. I have read that accelerometer is expensive, but wonder if its expensive then how many different things can be done that require motion sensing.

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/sensors/batching.html